# How to Collape/Expand group of cells in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to create a spreadsheet for training that lists each step in order, and want the ability for the person to click a box on a heading that will collapse the data underneath it so they are able to keep track of what is completed. However, the only thing I can find online is regarding grouping, which groups the entire row. I do not want to group the entire row, only individual cells. Is there any way around this?

This is what I want to group - 4 separate groups

*Current*
[image: Current]

This is how I envisioned it - clicking a checkbox to group/ungroup (pulled from another spreadsheet that is protected so I can't find the coding/formulas)

*Unchecked*
[image: Unchecked]

*Checked*
[image: Checked]
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This requires VBA - it's not possible with formulas :

- Save your spreadsheet as a macro-enabled `.xlsm` file
- Go to the Developer tab.
  If you don't see the Developer tab, go to
  [Show the Developer tab](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/show-the-developer-tab-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45).
- In the Controls group, click
  *Insert > checkbox (Active X Control)*.
  Important: You need to allow ActiveX to for this feature in
  *File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > ActiveX Settings*.
  More information in
  [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/enable-or-disable-activex-settings-in-office-files-f1303e08-a3f8-41c5-a17e-b0b8898743ed).
- Right-click the checkbox and select "View Code"
- In the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications window, copy and paste the following VBA code into the Code window:

  ```
  Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
      [6:9].EntireRow.Hidden = Not CheckBox1
  End Sub
  ```

  This assumes that the checkbox is named "CheckBox1" and the rows you
  wish to hide are `6:9`.
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>
  to close the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications window.